# Counting commas in a string with Javascript (AngularJS/Lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I have a rather specific problem.

I'm using ng-csv, and because it doesn't support nested arrays, I'm turning an array into a string.

Something like this:

```
[
 {"name":"Maria","chosen":false},
 {"name":"Jenny","chosen":false},
 {"name":"Ben","chosen":false},
 {"name":"Morris","chosen":false}
]
```

Turns into:

```
$scope.var = "Maria, Jenny, Ben, Morris"
```

My problem is that when I was using the array I was able to count the number of names in the array (which I need for UI reasons), but with the string it gets tricky.

Basically, I cannot count the number of words because some names might include last name, but I thought I could count commas, and then add 1.

Any pointers on how to do just that?

Comment: `commas = str.length - str.replace(/,/g, "").length;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need names itself - you may use method `split` of `String` class:

```
var str = "Maria, Jenny, Ben, Morris";
var arr = str.split(','); // ["Maria", " Jenny", " Ben", " Morris"]
var count = arr.length; // 4
```

Comment: Thanks to your solution I realized I can count names _before_ converting the array I already had to string : )

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Maria, Jenny, Ben, Morris";
var tokens = str.split(",");
```

The number of tokens should be captured in `tokens.length`.  Alternately, if you don't actually need to work with the tokens directly:

```
var nameCount = str.split(",").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex?

```
var _string = "Mary, Joe, George, Donald";

_string.match(/,/g).length // 3
```